# Quantum bases conversion ($S_x$, $S_y$, $S_z$)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space

As part of several of my homework problems on the subject, I've had to convert between bases, for instance $|+\mathbf{x}\rangle$ in the $S_z$ basis $\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |+\mathbf{z}\rangle + |-\mathbf{z}\rangle \right) \right)$ and so on, as a matter of course to solve various problems.  Using the right hand convention and the bare minimum examples given in my book (Townsend).

I haven't calculated all of them, and I haven't been able to see an easy to understand pattern between them at all.  Moreover, I haven't been able to locate a table of conversions.

Is there a pattern (so I can stop wasting a good 5 minutes converting between them using the basic formulas, and then making double and triple sure I didn't get the signs of the phases wrong and never ever being quite sure)?  And if so, may I get it explained to me?

Also, if it's not asking too much may I have a table of conversions in easy to read summary list format?  (I can do this part if it's too much to ask.)

Comment: Just rotate the ket in the z-basis over 90 degrees in the right direction, see  eq. 6.14 on page 32 of [these lecture notes](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/lieg07.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pattern. If you fix the eigenbasis of $S_z$ you have for any up $+$ or down $-$ eigenstate in $\vec{u}$ direction:
$$
\vec{u}=\sin\left(\theta\right) \cos \left(\phi\right)\vec{x}+\sin\left(\theta\right) \sin \left(\phi\right)\vec{y}+\cos\left(\theta\right)\vec{z}
$$
then
$$
S_u=\sin\left(\theta\right) \cos \left(\phi\right)S_x+\sin\left(\theta\right) \sin \left(\phi\right)S_y+\cos\left(\theta\right)S_z
$$
and the eigenvectors, using the commutation relation $[S_i\,,S_j]=i\varepsilon _{i,j,k}S_k$

$$
|u\,+\rangle= \cos \left(\theta\right) |z\,+\rangle + \sin \left(\theta\right) e^{i \phi} |z\,-\rangle
$$

$$
|u\,-\rangle= \sin \left(\theta\right) |z\,+\rangle - \cos \left(\theta\right) e^{i \phi} |z\,-\rangle
$$

Comment: This seems to help with converting to the $S_z$ basis.  What I'm having trouble with (for instance) is converting from $S_z$ to $S_y$ or $S_y$ to $S_x$ or similar.  I have $S_y$ and $S_x$ to $S_z$ calculated, and also $S_z$ to $S_x$ (I think!)  But I'm having trouble getting the rest of them.

Comment: I gave to you everything that you need. If you want $S_z \rightarrow S_x$ is only make $\vec{u}=\vec{x}$. If you want $S_y\rightarrow S_x$ make a cyclic permutation $(x,y,z)\rightarrow(z,x,y)$, and then $\vec{u}=\vec{y}$ (because before the cyclic permutation $x$ means $y$). And make the oposite cyclic permutation to recover what you want.

Comment: The cyclic permutation is to preserve the algebra.

Comment: So for a spin-1/2 particle and for $|+x\rangle$ in terms of $|\pm y\rangle$ we would perform a permutation $(x,y,z) \to (y, z, x)$ and get $\theta = \pi/2$ and $\phi = 0$.  So $|\pm x\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2} (|+y\rangle \pm |-y\rangle)$?

Comment: If you want x in terms of y the permutation need to be (z,x,y), because you want to deal in the basis of y and not x. You want to express x in terms of y basis.

Comment: So... $(x, y, z) \to (y, z, x)$ giving... what exactly for theta and phi?  Still pi/2 and 0?

Comment: Yes. Make a draw. Try to understand.